# Can you set a Canvas the Background of an element in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Apologies if this has been asked but I can't find the answer.  I have a couple of items (Windows, UserControls and DockPanels) that need dynamic backgrounds.

A Canvas object suits my needs well for the dynamic drawing, however, what I can't figure out is how (or even if) I can set a `<Canvas>` object as the value of a Background for a control object.

Can this be done and if yes, how?

Comment: Take a look at VisualBrush.

Comment: So you want to take the `Canvas` (and all of the elements inside it) and use it as a background of another `Control`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

```
<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red"></Rectangle><!-- Replace this with a reference to your Canvas-->
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

Code is referenced from [this site](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VisualBrush.aspx) there is a lot more that you can do with that background as well. Like set clipping etc ...
**Note**
Because you haven't specified the language you are developing it, I provided answer in the language I use namely `C#`, I don't use `VB`.

Comment: Made me smile... a pure XAML answer with a side note regarding VB.Net vs. C#

Comment: I believe this is the answer.  I've been torn in a couple directions.  I'll verify when I get the chance.

Comment: I'll give this an upvote. Bugs have kept me from returning to the related code.  For clarity, do I put a `<Canvas>` within the `<VisualBrush.Visual>`, or is the `<VisualBrush.Visual>` area basically a canvas-style object?

Answer (score 0):

Dou you want to set the Background property of a control with the "contents" of a Canvas already populated with elements?
If so, yes; it's possible to accomplish this task creating a Brush from your Canvas. To do it, you need the VisualBrush class. In VB.NET, use something like this:

```
Dim oBrush As New VisualBrush(myCanvas)
myControl.Background = oBrush
```

Good luck, good code